# What join do i need? Why doesn't my query work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out why I cannot get results in the format I need:

My databases structure example:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_b DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
USE test_b;


CREATE TABLE authors(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE galleries(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    author_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    published_at DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE articles(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    author_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    published_at DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Populating some test data into database:

```
INSERT INTO authors (id, name)
VALUES
(1, 'Mike'),
(2, 'John'),
(3, 'Stan');

INSERT INTO galleries (id, title, author_id, published_at)
VALUES
(1, 'gallery title 1', 1, now()),
(2, 'gallery title 2', 1, now()),
(3, 'gallery title 3', 1, now()),
(4, 'gallery title 4', 2, now()),
(5, 'gallery title 5', 2, now()),
(6, 'gallery title 6', 2, now()),
(7, 'gallery title 7', 3, now()),
(8, 'gallery title 8', 3, now()),
(9, 'gallery title 9', 3, now());


INSERT INTO articles (id, title, author_id, published_at)
VALUES
(1, 'article title 1', 1, now()),
(2, 'article title 2', 1, now()),
(3, 'article title 3', 1, now()),
(4, 'article title 4', 2, now()),
(5, 'article title 5', 2, now()),
(6, 'article title 6', 2, now()),
(7, 'article title 7', 3, now()),
(8, 'article title 8', 3, now()),
(9, 'article title 9', 3, now()),
(10, 'article title 10', 3, now()),
(11, 'article title 11', 3, now()),
(12, 'article title 12', 3, now());
```

I want to show a table of all published content for particular author like this (example for author id = 2) and I should be able to order by
title, content_type and published columns:

```
title,            content_type,        published
gallery title 4   gallery              DATETIME
gallery title 5   gallery              DATETIME 
gallery title 6   gallery              DATETIME
article title 4   article              DATETIME
article title 5   article              DATETIME
article title 6   article              DATETIME
```

Why doesn't my query work?

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.name,
CONCAT(IF(b.id IS NOT NULL,'gallery',''), IF(c.id IS NOT NULL,'article','')) as content_type,
CONCAT(COALESCE(b.title, ''), COALESCE(c.title, '')) AS title 
FROM authors as a
JOIN galleries AS b ON (a.id = b.author_id)
JOIN articles AS c ON (a.id = c.author_id)
WHERE a.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want `union all`:

```
select title, 'gallery' as content_type, published_at
from galleries
where author_id = 2
union all
select title, 'article', published_at
from articles
where author_id = 2;
```

Comment: But hw can I order by content_type or title?

Comment: `UNION` is bad, because it removes duplicates.  `UNION ALL` just combines two result sets, so it usually performs better.  In this case, the `UNION ALL` should add almost no overhead to running each query individually.  As for the second comment:  just add `order by content_type` or `order by title`.

Comment: And if I add `order by content_type` - that will be applied to the union result and not to the last select - right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct
a.id,
a.name,
CONCAT(IF(b.id IS NOT NULL,'gallery',''), IF(c.id IS NOT NULL,'article','')),
CONCAT(COALESCE(b.title, ''), COALESCE(c.title, '')) AS title 
FROM authors as a
JOIN galleries AS b ON a.id = b.author_id 
JOIN articles AS c ON a.id = c.author_id 
where a.id = 2;
```